# Chrome extension: How can I save an object to chrome.local.storage when closing a window?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying :

```
window.onunload = function(){
chrome.storage.sync.set(someObj);
}
```

It seems like that the popup window closes before the request is being made to the storage obj.

How can I store the obj before the window closes?

Comment: async code won't be executed so you need to switch to autosaving on each change instead.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks @wOxxOm :)

Comment: Maybe sendMessage will come through. The background page will listen and save the data.